# How TDengine downsampling queries

Tags: tdengine

How to perform downsampling queries on TDengine? For example, the original frequency of data was once per second, but now we want to perform one query every 10 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try interval() for down sampling.

Comment: Thank you very much. This method is effective.